# How can I tell Intellij IDEA to display decompiled source code in all cases

Tags: intellij-idea

When debugging using IDEA I want to click on the stack and see the code associated with that location.
Usually this works fine, click on the stack and see the code, OR click on the stack and see decompiled code.
But sometimes it will not decompile the code, and does not try to show the code.
Is there a setting that will force it to decompile the code and show it to me?

Comment: What exactly happens when you click on the stack frame? Please check if there are any related errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I didn't see anything in the log.  But I am debugging remotely and the stack position is in a jar that is not in my project on the machine I am running IDEA on.

Comment: Decompiler should work in all cases. We'd need the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to investigate it further.

Comment: Sadly an example is not an option at this time.  But I may have figured this out.  Seems like the project needs to have the code to decompile listed in the "External Libraries" if it isn't part of the source of the project.  And while debugging remotely, the remote system is loading a library that the local project doesn't have.  My assumption is that it needs a jar in its list of "External Libraries" to have a place to get the compiled code to decompile.   Perhaps the Java remote debugging system doesn't support providing IDEA with what it would need to show decompiled code.

Comment: Yes, you need to have all the libraries added to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency) if you want IDE to decompile the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make IDEA show decompiled code the class file for the code must be available.
Apparently this cannot be gotten from via the Java remote debug connection.

If you remote debug, and see a class in the stack trace that you want to see decompiled code for it must be added to what IDEA can see.

You can use the projects library settings to add a jar with the class in it, and then it will decompile it in this case.

In my case, I copied some jar files from the remote machine to my local machine.
I used "f4" to bring up the "Project Structure", then selected Libraries, used the "+" to add a new project library of type Java, and pointed it to the directory I put the jars in.  After which, at a break point, I could click on parts of the stack that used those classes, and it showed me decompiled code - AND I was able to place breakpoints in it the code at that point.